# Unable to change the Locale on a Glassfish v3 J2EE app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, locale, glassfish-3

My Dev server my glassfish web app reports that it has a local of en_US. This is causing the dates to be displayed in US format. I want us use locale en_GB for the dates.

My Dev server is a virtual box configured as follows:

- Ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS server
- Oracle Java 1.7.0_11
- GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
- GlassFish is running using upstart
- JavaServerFaces 1.2 Web app

Both the Host machine and the VM both return en_GB as the default OS locale

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

However in my web app when I write the locale to the log file, or when dates are displayed I can see that the locale is set to en_US.

```
                Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                log("Login.login_btn_action(): Default locale = " + locale.toString());
```

reports

```
Login.login_btn_action(): Default locale = en_US
```

To fix this I've tried the following (with no sucess):

1) In the Admin interface, selecting Domain and setting the locale to en_GB 
I can see that this setting appears in domain.xml in the first line:

2) Adding additional jvm-options in domain.xml to 'default-config' and 'server-config' to set user.language and user.country

```
    <jvm-options>-Duser.language=en</jvm-options>
    <jvm-options>-Duser.country=GB</jvm-options>
```

(Of course Each time I make a change I stop and start Glassfish)

Please can you suggest other options / settings to check / change to get my Java app to run with the native server locale?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc for [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29), you can change the default locale by using [`Locale.setDefault(Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29). Obviously, it isn't very nice to hard-code a locale in your app, so you could consider reading it from a config file or JVM option.

Comment: He might also try changing the date formats according to locale.

Comment: Thanks mthmulders for the suggestion. Using Locale.setDefault(Locale) is a work around.
However why Glassfish does not use the OS or jvm-option locale is still unanswered.....